# How i can create a Typescript interface that can take also a string?

Tags: typescript

I need to create an interface that permit to have an array of objects and strings.

For example:

```
const array = [
 '',
 {id: '', labels: ['']}
]
```

I've tried with:

```
export interface Obj{
  id: string;
  label: string[];
}

export interface Objs extends Array<Obj> {
}
```

But this don't permit strings so this return an error:

```
const array: Objs = [
 '',
 {id: '', labels: ['']}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use union types:

```js
export type Objs = Array<Obj | string>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the entries in the array can be either strings or objects in the form `{id: string; labels: string[]}`, you can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
export type Obj = string | {id: string; labels: string[]};
const array: Obj[] = [
    "",
    {id: "", labels: [""]}
];
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyAjAVnAvHAZxigEsA7AczgB84BvEgEwC5DjyKBuOAGwEMMwHgVZFSlANoBdAL6cAUAGMIZInD5QofRK0xZpeOBPlxTcAETmANCbMMWF67wFCRRy7PlTOQA)